Jmeter variables written into the csv file using the BeanShell Sampler are taking by the subsequent HTTP Requests
I am not sure what I am doing wrong
Login(Credentials /users) file has 4 Rows of data
Captured the variables using the Regular Expression and saved them into another CSV files using Bean Shell Sampler.
Extracted Variables Values are written into the file for Per Thread One Iteration as expected.
**Issue: **The problem is when I run the test extracted values are not picking from the file, instead of directly taking from the Regular Expression variable.
Details
When I ran the test for 2 Threads with 2 Iterations, My expectation was take only 2 users as file has tokens only for 2 users. When I looked at the  View Test Results Tree taking 2 more users for the 2nd Iteration  from the  file which indicated me extracted variables are not picking from the file .I expected on the 2nd Iteration also use the same users as  has extracted values only for 2 users.
Thread Group Design
User Defined Variables
[Users CSV File] 
Captured Variables(Tokens) has written into the CSV file
Variables Captured using Regular Expression
Bean shell Sampler
[Log] enter image description here
View Results Tree
BeanShell Sampler Code:

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

log.info("---------------------------Start-Write-Access-Token-File---------------------------------------------");

int iterationNumber = vars.getIteration();
String fileName = vars.get("login_landing_access-token");

// Clear the content of the file without removing the headers
if (iterationNumber == 1 && ctx.getThreadNum() == 0) {
    try {
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(fileName, false); // Pass 'false' to overwrite the file
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fstream);
        writer.print("");
        writer.close();
        log.info("File " + fileName + " content cleared.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error clearing file content: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

// Only write to file if it's the first iteration of each thread
if (iterationNumber == 1) {
String capturedAccessToken = vars.get("captured_access_token");
String capturedUserId = vars.get("captured_userid");
String capturedEmailAddress = vars.get("captured_user_emailaddress");
String capturedResponsebody = vars.get("captured_login_responsebody");

try {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileName, true);

    // Skip writing headers after clearing the file
    if (new File(fileName).length() == 0) {
       // writer.write("access_token, user_id, email_address, response_body\n");
        writer.write("captured_access_token,captured_userid,captured_user_emailaddress,captured_login_responsebody\n");
    }

    writer.append(capturedAccessToken.trim());
    writer.append(",");
    writer.append(capturedUserId.trim());
    writer.append(",");
    writer.append(capturedEmailAddress.trim());
    writer.append(",");
    writer.append(capturedResponsebody.trim());
    writer.append("\n");

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

   // log.info("Data appended to file for Thread " + ctx.getThreadNum() + "; Iteration Number: " + iterationNumber + "; user: " + vars.get("username"));
    log.info("Data appended to file for Thread " + vars.get("login_landing_access-token") + ctx.getThreadNum() + "; Iteration Number: " + iterationNumber + "; user: " + vars.get("username") + vars.get("captured_userid"));
    log.info("user_id: " + vars.get("captured_userid"));
    
  
} catch (IOException e) {
    log.error("Error writing to file: " + e.getMessage());
 }
}

log.info("---------------------------End-Write-Access-Token-File---------------------------------------------");


Write it to a queue, not a file.  Managing lock for multiple users on a common file is a nightmare and why service based solutions such as queues and database servers exist.  And also why file based solutions like MS Access only support a dozen users before crashing and burning.


Take a look at the JMeter Test Elements Execution Order, CSV Data Set Config is being initialized long before the Beanshell Sampler therefore either it reads the data from previous execution or fails

Using Beanshell for writing something into the same file with multiple threads at the same time is not a good idea, it might result into data corruption or loss, it's better to go for i.e. Flexible File Writer instead

Using Beanshell is not a good idea in general, since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting. See Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For? article for more information



Tried With Groovy, It's reaching to the file, but neither variables write nor throws any errors

Switching to groovy won't solve the issue, please re-read and try to understand point 1
